# Only load file from group drive which does not exist in datalake?

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I have data on a group drive and everyday a new file appears in this drive. The data is in csv format and should be copied to datalake in parquet. Is there a way to compare the file names (.csv / .parquet) and only copy the file to the datalake which does not exist there? I tried it with metadata but was not able to use the “name” in there to compare it with the name from the childitems from my data lake. Even if I get the name out of that array it would be useless to compare because the don’t have the same name because of the the “.csv” and “.parquet”hard to solve the problem as a beginner in this topic. The files have the identical “name” except the “.csv” and “.parquet”.

Any ideas for that?

Comment: are you able to get the file names list from your group drive?

Comment: No. I only get the array with name and Type in it. Was not able to split that to just get the name and use the substring out of that. @RakeshGovindula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are able to get the name and file Type JSON array, you can use the following method.

Here My source and target both are Data lake containers and I have used two Get Meta data activities to get the name and file Type JSON arrays like below.

**Source files child items(csvs) array:**

[image]

**Target files child items(parquets) array:**

[image]

In pipeline variables create two array variables to store the source and target file names list after split with `.`.

Take a ForEach and give Source child items array. Inside it use append activity with below expression.

`@split(item().name,'.')[0]`

[image]

Take another ForEach and do the same with target files array.

[image]

After that use a filter activity with below items and condition.

**items :** `@variables('sourcefilenames')`

**condition :** `@not(contains(variables('targetfilenames'), item()))`

[image]

**Filter output:**

[image]

To copy these files, use another Foreach to this array and inside use a copy activity with respective source and sink dataset parameters for filenames.

In copy activity source dataset parameter give this `@concat(item(),'.csv')` and for sink dataset parameter use this `@concat(item(),'.parquet')`.

Comment: You are my hero! Thank you very much!

Comment: Where can i find those parameter to put the code intoß i am little bit lost @RakeshGovindula

Comment: create the dataset parameters for source and sink(new datasets with foldernames and in filename give the dataset parameter in dataset). In copy activity, you can find the parameter. Give the dataset parameter like this example in the file path of dataset for source and sink datasets https://i.imgur.com/H62untA.png.

Comment: Everything is working now. Thanks a lot :)